# PayPal pause subcription API in react returning error

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to implement the pause subscription API for Paypal in my React app.

I don't think I am really understanding properly how to do this.

First I am trying to generate an auth token, and then use that in the pause subscription API.

The original code from the documentation is a curl so I have changed it to axios, but I don't think I am using it correctly.

Here is the code I am using:

```
async function cancel() {

const response = await axios.post(
    'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    new URLSearchParams({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }),
    {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US'
        },
        auth: {
            username: 'MY CLIENT ID IS HERE',
            password: 'MY SECRET IS HERE'
        }
    }
);

const response2 = await axios.post(
  'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G/suspend',
  '',
  {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: response.data.access_token
      }
  }
);
}
```

This is the error the console returns:

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar error also when trying to create a plant, product..

request:

```
const response = await axios.post(
      'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans',
      {
          // 'product_id': 'PROD-XXCD1234QWER65782',
          'name': `Plan - ${paiement_cycle} subscription for ${company} with total amount USD${parsed_price}`,
          'description': `${paiement_cycle} subscription for ${company} with total amount ${parsed_price}. subscribed by ${name}`,
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'billing_cycles': [
              {
                  'frequency': {
                      'interval_unit': 'MONTH',
                      'interval_count': 1
                  },
                  // 'tenure_type': 'REGULAR',
                  // 'sequence': 1,
                  'pricing_scheme': {
                      'fixed_price': {
                          'value': parsed_price*100,
                          'currency_code': 'USD'
                      }
                  }
              },
          ],
      },
      {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `${token_type} ${access_token}`,
              'PayPal-Request-Id': `${pro_seq}`
          }
        }
    );
```

response:

```
    {
  "name": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
  "message": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
  "debug_id": "be19a801e3232",
  "details": [
    {
      "issue": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
      "description": "You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#NOT_AUTHORIZED",
      "rel": "information_link",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Axios returns a promise. You have to use either .then() or `await` for it to resolve, and you must actually parse the resulting JSON string (axios does this automatically, fetch would not) and get the access_token string value out of it. Then you can use this value in the authorization header of your request.

So, it may be as simple as adding an await:

```
const response = await axios.post(
```

And then:

```
      Authorization: response.data.access_token
```

Comment: I see, yes. I'm still getting an error back from this? I've updated the post with screenshot of the error and what I have edited the code to be

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct credentials for sandbox.

Comment: The credentials match those in my sandbox account

Comment: Is the first post receiving an access_token

Comment: It is, yes. I can log that in the console and see the access token using response.data.access_token

Comment: What's the full response text of the second call then

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of the full response section from the console. It does say: 'Authentication failed due to invalid authentication creden'

Comment: Your screenshot only show the beginning of the response text

Comment: Also you're doing the call from a browser; calls with a client id + secret are to be done from a backend (node.js or whatever). The 'secret' should never be on the client side.

Comment: I'm not really sure where in the app folder to put the file with the backend things in. The app folder structure has: a folder called 'app', then inside there is the 'public' and 'src folders. Where are the backend servers supposed to go?

Comment: Perhaps the Full Stack example at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ would be useful as a starting point. It doesn't use react, and its post is done with fetch instead of axios, but it should get you started with something that works for doing such API calls, and you can change those Order API calls to do a subscription suspend